# change font size of label of vertex in tkz-graph?

Tags: fontsize, tkz-graph

I am currently writing a tex-file in which I also need to create a graph and label the vertices. I am using the package tkz-graph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
 \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
    \SetUpEdge
    \SetGraphUnit{1.5}
    \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape = circle,  minimum size = 30pt, draw}}


    \Vertex[L = a,  x = -2, y = 2]{a}
    \Vertex[L = abcdef,  x = 2, y = 2]{abcdef}

    \Edge[lw=1pt](a)(abcdef)
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The two vertices than appear in different size because the label of the second one is to big and then it automatically increases the size of vertex. I want to change the font size of the label of this vertex but I don't know how and I did not find it in the documentation.
So how do I change the font size of the label of single vertices? If this is not possible how do I change the font size of the labels for all vertices?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Is it now better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set font for all vertices, you can add tikz node options to `Vertexstyle`, for example `\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style={..., font=\large}}`.

To set font for a single vertex, you can use `\Vertex[..., style={<tikz node options>}] {...}`.

Caution: currently local styles (`style=...`) will be overwritten by the global ones (`VertexStyle/.style=...`). In the example below, `\xpatchcmd` from `regexpatch` is used to change this.

A full list of tikz node font options is documented in `pgfmanual` v3.1.9a, sec. 17.4.2 "Text Parameters: Font".

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % not necessary because `tikz-graph` will auto load tikz
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\@@vertex}
  {\cmdGR@vertex@style,\nstyle}
  {\nstyle,\cmdGR@vertex@style}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
    \SetUpEdge
    \SetGraphUnit{1.5}
    \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape = circle,  minimum size = 30pt, draw, text=blue}}

    % vertex a, "node font=\Large, text=red" (global "text=blue" is overwritten by the local)
    \Vertex[L = a,  x = -2, y = 2, style={node font=\Large, text=red}]{a}
    % vertex b, "text=blue, font=\bfseries"
    \Vertex[L = abcdef,  x = 2, y = 2, style={font=\bfseries}]{abcdef}

    \Edge[lw=1pt](a)(abcdef)
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can also use several `\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style ...`

Comment: @AlainMatthes Hi Alain, to the option precedence issue I've opened https://github.com/tkz-sty/tkz-graph/issues/1 under which David Carlisle questioned if that repo should be archived.

Comment: I'm not a great expert in using `GitHub` but you are right it would be better to reverse the styles.

Comment: I will make an update in the next days.